# How to upgrade old Navigation Drawer Fragment code to the code using toolbar instead of Action bar?

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, upgrade, toolbar

1.Toolbar is declared in XML and included in the concerned XML

2. restoreActionbar function given in the code (at the bottom) is midified as per the net instruction for Actionbar to Toolbar still it is not working.
3. This is the Standard Navigation Drawer Fragment code provided earlier for menu option. Is there an example code where it is upgraded to the toolbar from Action bar.
4. Firstly tried in OnCreate method (commented in following code) - not working, Tried to declare it globally(commented in the following code) not working.
   Please help

public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity implements
NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

```
/**
 * Fragment managing the behaviors, interactions and presentation of the
 * navigation drawer.
 */
private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;

/**
 * Used to store the last screen title. For use in
 * {@link #restoreActionBar()}.
 */
private CharSequence mTitle;
//private int mPosition = 0;
private String mMessage;
//private int mSectionNo =0;
private String mMenuType="";
private Random r1 = new Random();
private Random r2 = new Random();
Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    
    //Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
    //mSectionNo = g.getData();
    mMenuType = g.getMenuType();
    
    //Intent intent = getIntent();
    //mMessage = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity1);
     
    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();
    /*if (mMessage.equals("1")){
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.mSectionNo = 1;
    }*/

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

       int radioId=sharedPreferences.getInt("shapecheck", 0);
       if(radioId>0){
       g.mShapeOption = 1;  
       }
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    //mPosition = position;
    Globals g = Globals.getInstance();
    g.setSectionType(position);
    
    if ((mMenuType.equals("2to10"))||(mMenuType.equals("11to20"))||(mMenuType.equals("21to30")))
            {
            if(position==10){
            this.finish();} // to exit
    }
    if ((mMenuType.equals("randomizer")) ||(mMenuType.equals("sequential"))||(mMenuType.equals("quiz"))||(mMenuType.equals("query"))){
        if(position==4){
        this.finish();
    }
    }
    if ((mMenuType.equals("about")) || (mMenuType.equals("shapeoption"))){
        if(position==1){
        this.finish();
    }
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container,
                    PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1)).commit();
    //TextView txtView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView79);
    //txtView1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.nine);
}

public void onSectionAttached(int number) {
    switch (number) {
    case 1:
        case1Selection();
        break;
    case 2:
        case2Selection();
        break;
    case 3:
        case3Selection();
        break;
    case 4:
        case4Selection();
        break;
    case 5:
        case5Selection();
        break;
    case 6:
        case6Selection();
        break;
    case 7:
        case7Selection();
        break;
    case 8:
        case8Selection();
        break;
    case 9:
        case9Selection();
        break;
    case 10:
        case10Selection();
        break;
    case 11:
        case11Selection();
        break;
    }
}

public void restoreActionBar() {
    //Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    //Toolbar toolbar getSupportActionBar();
    //toolbar.setnavigationMode(Toolbar.NAV)
    //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    //actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_STANDARD);
    //actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    toolbar.setTitle(mTitle);
    //actionBar.setTitle(mTitle);
}
```